# AngularJS ngSubmitted is falsely false

Tags: angularjs

This code is where the oddity happens, triggered by a submit button.

```js
var form = $scope.addOrderForm;
console.log(form);
console.log(form.$submitted);
```

When I view the output of console.log(form), the $submitted property in Chrome's Dev tools shows "true", but using that same variable, console.log(form.$submitted) is showing "false". If I click the submit button one more time, both show "true". I'm perplexed as to this behavior. The $submitted property is yielding different results based on whether I log the entire form object, or just the property. Can anyone suggest why this might happen?

DEMO:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("TestController", function($scope) {
  $scope.submitHandler = function() {
    alert("Form submitted");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="TestController" class="container">
  <form name="myForm" id="myForm" ng-submit="submitHandler()">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>First Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="firstName" data-ng-model="firstName" class="form-control" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="lastName" data-ng-model="lastName" class="form-control" />
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        {{myForm.$submitted ? 'Submitted' : 'Submit'}}
      </button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I have added a snippet for you. Please update it to show your issue.

Comment: Just as a tip : When you log a non-object / non-array value, what is shown in the console is the value the item had at the `console.log(...)` line.
However when you log an object you dev tool will update the output log as the object properties change. If you want to be sure about the state of an object at the time the `console.log` is called, you should try something like `console.log(angular.copy(...))`